# Alternatives for HornetsEye - Ruby

Tags: ruby, image-processing, video-processing, visual-programming

I installed [HornetsEye](https://github.com/wedesoft/hornetseye-narray), that "real-time computer vision library" for some experiments with my webcam. I want to know if are there other alternatives in ruby?

Comment: By the way, could you explain what problem you have with HornetsEye ? (I wanted to try it, so having some more info would be good)

Answer (score 1):

RMagick comes to mind, but it is not very very performant ...

I have not tested it yet personally, but since OpenCV is definitely the way to go from C++, the ruby-opencv gem could be interesting. I could only find this one actively developped, though.

http://github.com/ruby-opencv/ruby-opencv

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [Camellia Image Processing Library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/camellia/) interests you because.

It has been written in C but has a native wrapper for RUBY and its performance is very good.

Comment: Do you know if it is still being actively developped ? It does not look that way from the SVN statistics on sourceforge.